# Почему koala ругается на переменные?

Tags: sass, nwjs

В style.sass подключаю файл _variables.sass: @import 'variables'. В самом файле variables - $text-color-dark: #333333. В файле style: color: $text-color-dark. Koala пишет: Error: Undefined variable: $text-color-dark. Почему koala не может определить переменную? [image: style.sass]

[image: variables.sass]

Comment: `@media 'variables'` это что такое? `@import '_variables'` же для подключения

Comment: Да, извеняюсь, в вопросе ошибка. У меня в style.sass - @import 'variables'

Comment: Тогда может быть проблема например в очередности подключения и вызова. лучше полностью пример выложите, в том виде, как вы описали, все должно работать

Comment: Как и написал @ArtemGorlachev у вас проблема в очередноси. Файлы нужно подключать перед вызовом переменных. А так, вы сначала вызываете переменную, а только потом подключаете.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло